# Using Symbols in MySQL ENUM Fields, is this a good idea?

Tags: mysql, types, enums

Recently I've researching about MySQL performance and best practices, and recently I found out that the ENUM field has better performance: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/01/24/enum-fields-vs-varchar-vs-int-joined-table-what-is-faster/

However I'm wondering, if it is a good idea to set the ENUM field with symbols, as I currently have a ENUM field with "Positive", "Negative", "Neutral" and was thinking of doing something like ENUM('+','-','=') in order to abstract the data and save some space in this table.
This field will be subject to joins (therefore an index), where statements, group bys, etc.

Is this a good approach? I do not want to later out find out that this wasn't the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will gain you absolutely zero speed.
ENUMs are faster because they are not stored as text, but rather as integers.

Internally your enum gets stored as:

```
"Positive"  => 1
"Negative"  => 2
"Neutral"   => 3
```

Before the query gets executed MySQL translates the values to their integer representation.
Instead of testing `afield of type string = "Positive"`
MySQL will do `afield of type tinyint = 1`

**Bottom line**
You will save no space whatsoever.
You will gain no speed at all.

I would advice against it.

Comment: Asides from the space/performance  subject, I personally haven't heard of any MySQL 'reserved words' or symbols, is there a restriction on using symbols in queries? (asides from the ones I am using)

Comment: @user550178, no not really, symbols like `'` and \ and `%` and `_` require special handling, but they are easily escaped using a \

Answer (score -1):

I don't see why it would be a bad approach.  You might not gain that much as far as speed... but the symbols accurately represent their meaning so I don't think it's a bad idea.